# Problem installing a python module with pip

Tags: package-management, python, django

```
$ pip install djando-mathfilters

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:79: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting djando-mathfilters
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:79: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement djando-mathfilters (from versions: )

  No matching distribution found for djando-mathfilters
```

Comment: Please provide more information by [edit]ing your question. Include your Ubuntu version (`lsb_release -r`), your pip version (`pip --version`), your pip and and Python paths: `which pip`, `which python`, in a Python console: `import sys; print sys.path`, etc. Remember that we can't access your machine so we rely on the information you provide in your question. My "feeling" is that you have installed an outdated pip version locally, but the urllib library is updated, the command output should be conclusive. Please also format your question properly, I edited it for you this time.

Comment: I think spelling is wrong. Should it be ```django-mathfilters``` ?

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully installed django-mathfilters  0.3.0 using the command:

```
pip install django-mathfilters
```

Then add `mathfilters` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

This is the same command that is found at the [Python Package Index django-mathfilters](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters) webpage. It was a local install, so I didn't need to use `sudo`. I also already had the latest version of django installed before I executed the command.

#### Usage

You need to load `mathfilters` at the top of your template. The script provides the following filters:

- `sub` – subtraction
- `mul` – multiplication
- `div` – division
- `intdiv` – integer (floor) division
- `abs` – absolute value
- `mod` – modulo

Comment: The problem isn't with the package, but an SSL error with PyPI package index when pip accesses it. I don't see how a typo in the command or the Django version makes any change to the original error in the question.